# Can I fly under a Military Operations Area (MOA)?

Tags: faa-regulations, special-use-airspace

If a  a Military Operations Area (MOA) is designated from 10,000 to 18,000 feet, can I fly under the airspace without any permission?

Comment: You can fly IN an MOA without permission, so you can certainly fly under one.

Comment: @Dave-CFII -- that's true for VFR, but not necessarily for IFR.  And it's often ill-advised to fly in a MOA even VFR: students flying formation & acrobatics at speeds up to 500 kts don't really mix well with General Aviation aircraft at ~100 knots.  That all said, the floor is the floor and your point about flying under one is entirely correct.

Comment: Under IFR you really don't fly anywhere without a permission from ATC, unless you are handling an emergency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. The MOA floor, 10000ft in this case, is the lower limit of any restrictions a MOA imposes. Otherwise there would be no point in assigning a floor to MOA (or any other airspace for that matter)
See [FAA AIM Section 4. Special Use Airspace](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap3_section_4.html)